# Youtube player crashes when switching between landscape and portrait

Tags: youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api, youtubeplayer

I am using Android Youtube Player as

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/idRVUsers"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>
```

with a recyclerview component on the same layout.

I have initialized youtube player as

```
static String[] mStrings;

private YouTubePlayerView mYouTubePlayerView;
private YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener mOnInitializedListener;
private YouTubePlayer mYouTubePlayer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondscreen);

    youTubePlayerSetup();  //Initialized successfully.

    getDataFromAPI(new VolleyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONArray result){
            //do stuff here
            loadingPB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SUCCESS",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    // creating a new array list.
    userModalArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    // initializing our views.
    userRV = findViewById(R.id.idRVUsers);
}
```

When I play some video using its id and does play however it crashes when I switched to Landscape mode and back to portrait using youtube ui fullscreen controls.

Youtube Player Crashes and throws this error:
**attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.loadVideo(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried.
Added this line
**android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"**
in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.secondscreen"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"/>
```

it now handles orientation changes. and no crash problem seems to occur now.